# Como puedo convertir un array de tipo string a un array de tipo int? (De texto a entero)

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando con Arrays en c# y necesio convertir lo que tengo en mi array de tipo texto a numeros, para ordenarlos de mayor a manor

```
        string numeros;
        Console.WriteLine("DIGITE NUMEROS SEPARADOS POR COMA (,): ");
        numeros = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] arreglo = numeros.Split(',');
        for(int i=0; i<arreglo.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(arreglo[i]+"-");

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede usar varias maneras para conseguirlo:

**Método 1: Usando bucle for**

Creamos un arreglo nuevo de tipo *int*. Y luego, usando el bucle *for*, vamos a pasar a través de `arreglo`, convertir cada elemento a un *string*, y guárdalo en el arreglo nuevo.

```
int[] arregloInt = new int[arreglo.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.Length; i++)
{
    arregloInt[i] = Convert.ToInt32(arreglo[i]);
}
```

**Método 2: Usando LINQ**

O podemos usar la consulta LINQ para convertir el arreglo de *string* a un arreglo de *int*. Este código de abajo devuelve el mismo resultado que con el código del método 1.

```
int[] arregloInt2 = arreglo.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

---

Si quiere imprimir el arreglo de `int`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arregloInt.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arregloInt[i].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Como puedo convertir un array de tipo string a un array de tipo int? (De texto a entero)

El algoritmo para poder realizar este tipo de conversión sería:

- Obtener la longitud adecuada al momento de reservar memoria para el arreglo de tipo `Integer`. 
  Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa la siguiente sucesión: `23,6,9,2`, el tamaño del arreglo debería ser 4, porqué en el conjunto sólo hay 4 números.
- Luego debemos ejecutar un bucle para recorrer la cadena ingresada por el usuario, esto nos servirá para realizar la conversión.
- Por último, debemos asignarle al bucle la forma de realizar esa conversión. Por ejemplo, si la sucesión ingresada es: `234,35,6`, nuestro método debe tener dos variables:

  - Debemos tener una variable (puede ser `int j`) que nos permita contar el índice en cada iteración, siempre y cuando `numeros[indice]` sea igual a una `coma`, debido que, necesitamos asignar el valor convertido en una determinada posición del arreglo de tipo `Integer`.
  - La segunda variable (puede ser `int valor`) es para guardar el valor ya convertido (el número estará en caracter, hay que convertirlo a `integer`).

Empecemos a crear nuestro método que nos permitirá obtener la longitud del arreglo de tipo `Int`.

```
    //Obtiene la nueva longitud del arreglo de tipo Entero
    public int GetLengthArrayInt(string number)
    {
        int lenNumber = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i != number.Length; ++i)
        {
            //Contamos cada coma de la sucesión ingresada por el usuario
            if(number[i] == ',')
                ++lenNumber;
        }
        /*
            Si por ejemplo, la sucesión fue 23,34,4 
            lenNumber valdría 2, sumándole 1, nos daría la cantidad de números ingresado por el usuario
        */
        return lenNumber + 1;
    }
```

Para explicar el funcionamiento del método, lo plantearé en un ejemplo: Asumamos que el usuario ingresa `23,33,6,45`, entonces esa cadena estará en un objeto (el puntero `string number` hace referencia hacia ese objeto).

Cuando el método `GetLengthArrayInt` se ejecute, estaríamos contando las `comas` de la sucesión: `23,33,6,45`, esto quiere decir, que al final, `lenNumber`
valdrá 3 (porqué hay 3 comas en la sucesión). Entonces para poder saber cual será la longitud del arreglo de tipo `int`, le sumo un `+1` a `lenNumber`, de este modo, el método `GetLengthArrayInt` retornará el tamaño de elementos del arreglo (que en este caso, sería 4).

Ahora, crearemos un método llamado `ConvertToArrayInt` para que nos realice la conversión:

```
    public int[] ConvertToArrayInt(string number)
    {
        int j = 0;
        int valor = 0;  
        //Reservamos memoria para crear el arreglo de X elementos
        int[] num = new int[GetLengthArrayInt(number)];
        for(int i = 0; i != number.Length; ++i)
        {
            /*
                Asignamos el número en X posición al arreglo de tipo Integer, 
                solo pasa cada vez que encontramos una coma.
            */
            if(number[i] == ',')
            {
                num[j++] = valor;
                valor = 0;
                continue;
            }
            //Convertimos cada caracter al número esperado hasta llegar a una coma
                    valor = (valor * 10) + (number[i] - '0');
            }
        }
        //Asignamos el número al arreglo, asumiendo que el último número de la sucesión no tiene una coma
        num[j++] = valor;

        //Retornamos el objeto creado
        return num;
    }
```

El funcionamiento del código sería:
Teniendo ya la longitud del arreglo de tipo `int`, podemos proceder a reservar 4 espacios de memoria para los elementos: `23,33,6,45`.

Entonces, este método hará que cuando la variable `i` tome los valores (`0 y 1`), la variable `valor` tendrá listo el número convertido a `integer` (`valor` será igual a `23`). Cuando i sea igual a 2, la condición: `number[i] == ','` se evaluará y en ese momento, debemos pasar el contenido que tenga la variable `valor`, a la posición `0` del arreglo `num`(por eso es necesario declarar la variable `int j`, representa el índice/posición del arreglo `num`).

El mismo proceso de arriba será exactamente igual cuando i valga `3 y 4`, la variable `valor` tendrá ya convertido el número `33` en `integer` y se procede asignarlo en la posición `1` del arreglo `num` (tipo `int`).

Me saltaré algunas iteraciones... Y asumiré que la variable `i` llegó a la posición `8`, estaríamos conviertiendo el dígito `4` a `integer` y del mismo modo con el dígito `5`, por lo tanto, la variable `valor` tendrá ya el número 45 convertido a `integer`. El bucle finalizaría y tocaría asignar el valor de 45 en la última posición (j = `3`) del arreglo `num`.

Por último, el método retornaría el objeto de tipo `integer`.

El problema radica que la sucesión debe seguir el formato: `12,34,...,n`, es decir, el usuario no puede ingresar caracteres que no sean numéricos, ni tampoco pueden escribir comas en cualquier lado.

Por ejemplo: El usuario no puede escribir esto:

- `34,,,34`
- `,,,,`
- `4,f,4g`
- `,34,45,`, entre otros casos.

Por esa razón, necesitamos realizar una validación para que nuestro programa no se caiga.

Entonces, crearemos un método llamado `ValidString` para que nos valide la cadena ingresada por el usuario:

```
    //Detecta si ingresó la sucesión con el formato: {1,23,2,5, ..., n}
    public bool ValidString(string number)
    {
        int countNumber = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i != number.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(number[i] == ',')
            {
                if(countNumber == 0)
                    return true;
                countNumber = 0;
            }
            //Verificamos si el caracter es númerico
            else if(!(number[i] >= '0' && number[i] <= '9'))
                return true;
            //Contamos cada dígito antes de llegar a la coma
            else 
                ++countNumber;
        }
        return (countNumber == 0) ? (true) : (false);
    }
```

Vamos asumir que el usuario ingresa lo siguiente: `44,,45,`
El método lo que hará es contar los números que estén a lado (a la izquierda) de la coma.

En este caso, la variable `CountNumber` valdrá 2, cuando i valga (`0 y 1`), hasta ahí todo esta bien, debido a que, la condición: `if(countNumber == 0)` será `false` (cuando i valga `2`), posteriormente, re-inicializamos la variable `countNumber` a 0.

Cuando i valga `3`, la condición: `if(countNumber == 0)` se evaluaría y daría como resultado un `true`, porqué la variable `countNumber` se quedó en 0, entonces, el método retorna `true` porqué hubo un error en la validación.

Para llevar un mayor orden, agregaremos todos estos métodos en una clase llamada `Convertion`:

```
class Convertion
{
    //Convierte el array tipo string a Integer.
    public int[] ConvertToArrayInt(string number)
    {
        int j = 0;
        int valor = 0;

        //Validamos el string antes de realizar la conversión...
        if(ValidString(number)) 
        {
            Console.Write("Error: Has ingresado una sucesión errónea\n\n");
            return null;
        }

        //Reservamos memoria para crear el arreglo de X elementos
        int[] num = new int[GetLengthArrayInt(number)];
        for(int i = 0; i != number.Length; ++i)
        {
            /*
                Asignamos el número en X posición al arreglo de tipo Integer, 
                solo pasa cada vez que encontramos una coma.
            */
            if(number[i] == ',')
            {
                num[j++] = valor;
                valor = 0;
                continue;
            }
            //Convertimos cada caracter al número esperado hasta llegar a una coma
            valor = (valor * 10) + (number[i] - '0');
        }
        //Asignamos el número al arreglo, asumiendo que el último número de la sucesión no tiene una coma
        num[j++] = valor;

        //Retornamos el objeto creado
        return num;
    }

    //Detecta si ingresó la sucesión con el formato: {1,23,2,5, ..., n}
    public bool ValidString(string number)
    {
        int countNumber = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i != number.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(number[i] == ',')
            {
                if(countNumber == 0)
                    return true;
                countNumber = 0;
            }
            //Verificamos si el caracter es númerico
            else if(!(number[i] >= '0' && number[i] <= '9'))
                return true;
            //Contamos cada dígito antes de llegar a la coma
            else 
                ++countNumber;
        }
        return (countNumber == 0) ? (true) : (false);
    }

    //Obtiene la nueva longitud del arreglo de tipo Entero
    public int GetLengthArrayInt(string number)
    {
        int lenNumber = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i != number.Length; ++i)
        {
            //Contamos cada coma de la sucesión ingresada por el usuario
            if(number[i] == ',')
                ++lenNumber;
        }
        /*
            Si por ejemplo, la sucesión fue 23,34,4 
            lenNumber valdría 2, sumándole 1, nos daría la cantidad de números ingresado por el usuario
        */
        return lenNumber + 1;
    }
}
```

El modo de uso de la clase sería:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        string numeros;
        int[] num;
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DIGITE NUMEROS SEPARADOS POR COMA (,): ");
            numeros = Console.ReadLine();

            //Creamos el objeto..
            Convertion con = new Convertion();

            //Verificamos si hubo algún error al momento de hacer la conversión..
            if((num = con.ConvertToArrayInt(numeros)) == null)
                continue;

            //Imprimimos cada elemento del arreglo de tipo int.
            for(int i= 0; i != num.Length; i++)
                Console.Write(num[i] + " - ");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

También debo recalcar, que falta una validación y es que debemos detectar cuando ocurra un [desbordamiento numérico](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception?view=netframework-4.8) (o también llamado overflow).

Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa lo siguiente: `233323232323232323,34,4`, el primer elemento se estaría pasando del tamaño máximo de un `ìnteger`(que suelen ser 4 bytes).

La solución sería usar la palabra clave `checked` para poder habilitar la comprobación del `overflow` y adicional a eso, utilizar el `try-catch` para detectar la excepción.

Esta comprobación la debemos agregar cuando hagamos la conversión de un caracter a `integer`:

```
    public int[] ConvertToArrayInt(string number)
    {
        int j = 0;
        int valor = 0;

        //Validamos el string antes de realizar la conversión...
        if(ValidString(number)) 
        {
            Console.Write("Error: Has ingresado una sucesión errónea\n\n");
            return null;
        }

        //Reservamos memoria para crear el arreglo de X elementos
        int[] num = new int[GetLengthArrayInt(number)];
        for(int i = 0; i != number.Length; ++i)
        {
            /*
                Asignamos el número en X posición al arreglo de tipo Integer, 
                solo pasa cada vez que encontramos una coma.
            */
            if(number[i] == ',')
            {
                num[j++] = valor;
                valor = 0;
                continue;
            }
            //Habilita la comprobación del overflow...
            checked
            {
                //Detectamos el overflow...
                try 
                {
                    //Convertimos cada caracter al número esperado hasta llegar a una coma
                    valor = (valor * 10) + (number[i] - '0');
                }
                catch(OverflowException)
                {
                    Console.Write("Error: Ingresaste un entero muy grande...");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        //Asignamos el número al arreglo, asumiendo que el último número de la sucesión no tiene una coma
        num[j++] = valor;

        //Retornamos el objeto creado
        return num;
    }
```